# Getting a null reference while trying to verify a signature using MimeKit

Tags: nullreferenceexception, smime, mimekit

I'm currently working on a `proof of concept` to implement an AS2 client. I have set up a `consle application` that works as the sender, and a `ASP .Net API` that works as the receiver. I tried to achieve this using the `Windows.Security` library but there too, there were problem with verifying the signatutre. Then I found `MimeKit` which seemed easier to use.

While trying to find a solution to my problem it seemed to me that most of the questions on "how to verify a signature" the answers where to do a `foreach` loop on the signatures in a `MultipartSigned`, I tried to do that, but it didn't help me.

`decrypted` is a `MimeEntity` that contains the whole message.

The null reference occurs the when I call `signed.Verify();`.

```cs
var signed = decrypted as MultipartSigned;
if (signed != null) {
    using (var ctx = new TemporaryMimeContext ()) {
        foreach (var signature in signed.Verify (ctx)) {
            try {
                bool valid = signature.Verify ();
            } catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException) {
                // There was an error verifying the signature.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should happen is that the signatures should be OK, but what actually happens is that an `null refrence exception` occurs inside of the assembly files.

The stack trace looks like this

```
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.<GetDigitalSignaturesAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.Verify(Stream content, Stream signatureData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.MultipartSigned.Verify(CryptographyContext ctx, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at AS2_Proof_of_Concept.WebAPI.Controllers.MimeKitController.IncomingMessage() in C:\Users\chris\source\repos\AS2 Proof of Concept\AS2_Proof_of_Concept\AS2_Proof_of_Concept.WebAPI\Controllers\MimeKitController.cs:line 104
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<WrapVoidMethod>b__0(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.VoidResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

***EDIT***

Here is how the `signed` message looks like.

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha-256; boundary="----=_Part_946d8daa50ab44b699f82dbd3c6bacc0"

------=_Part_946d8daa50ab44b699f82dbd3c6bacc0
Content-Type: application/EDIFACT
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment filename= HelloWorld.txt

test
------=_Part_946d8daa50ab44b699f82dbd3c6bacc0
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment filename="smime.p7s"
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------=_Part_946d8daa50ab44b699f82dbd3c6bacc0--
```

Comment: Would it be possible to save the `signed` part to disk and send it to me so that I can figure out what is `null`? Looking at the code, I don't see any obvious cause of an NRE. The other option is to build a debug version of MimeKit and step thru the `BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.GetDigitalSignaturesAsync()` method to see what the problem is and let me know what variable is null so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

While stepping through the `BounncyCastleMimeContext.GetDigitalSignatureAsync()` method, I found out that the `SignerInformation.SignedAttributes` at `SecureMimeDigitalSignature (SignerInformation signerInfo, X509Certificate certificate)` was `null` and then that null refrence caused the `signature.EncryptionAlgorithms` to be `null` too.

Comment: This is now fixed in the latest pre-release builds located at https://www.myget.org/feed/mimekit/package/nuget/MimeKit

Answer (score 0):

This was a legitimate bug in Mime 2.1.4 that is now fixed in build 2.1.4.9 located at https://www.myget.org/feed/mimekit/package/nuget/MimeKit